# How to debounce Formik Field ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, formik, debouncing

I want to debounce Formik `<Field/>` but when I type in the field seems debounce does not work. Also I have tried lodash.debounce, throttle-debounce and the same result. How to solve this?

**CodeSandbox** - https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-nobel-7p6nt

**Snippet**:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { withFormik, Field, Form } from "formik";

const App = ({ setFieldValue }) => {
  let timeout;
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  const onChange = text => {
    if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => setText(text), 750);
  };

  return (
    <Form>
      <Field
        type="text"
        name="textField"
        placeholder="Type something..."
        onChange={e => {
          onChange(e.target.value);
          setFieldValue("textField", e.target.value);
        }}
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
      />
      <br />
      <br />
      <div>output: {text}</div>
    </Form>
  );
};

const Enhanced = withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues: () => ({
    textField: ""
  }),
  handleSubmit: (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    setSubmitting(false);
    return false;
  }
})(App);

ReactDOM.render(<Enhanced />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [t, setT] = useState(null);

  const onChange = text => {
    if (t) clearTimeout(t);
    setT(setTimeout(() => setText(text), 750));
  };
```

Comment: The best and simplest solution!

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest to move the call inside of timeout function.

```
const App = ({ setFieldValue }) => {
      let timeout;
      const [text, setText] = useState("");

      const onChange = text => {
        if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(() => {
          setText(text);
          //changing value in container
          setFieldValue("textField", text);
        }, 750);
      };

      return (
        <Form>
          <Field
            type="text"
            name="textField"
            placeholder="Type something..."
            onChange={e => {
              onChange(e.target.value);
            }}
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
          />
          <br />
          <br />
          <div>output: {text}</div>
        </Form>
      );
    };
```

Comment: But what if I have 50+ inputs?

Comment: You would have to declare several state or use array, you would have to offer the name of the field in the call to onChange. Always change the state at the right time, remember that the changes give rise to a new render.

Comment: Also the <FieldArray/> :)

Answer (score 0):

## Using Custom Hooks

This is abstracted from the answer provided by @Skyrocker

If you find yourself using this pattern a lot you can abstract it out to a [custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html).

### `hooks/useDebouncedInput.js`

```js
const useDebouncedInput = ({ defaultText = '', debounceTime = 750 }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState(defaultText)
  const [t, setT] = useState(null)

  const onChange = (text) => {
    if (t) clearTimeout(t)
    setT(setTimeout(() => setText(text), debounceTime))
  }

  return [text, onChange]
}

export default useDebouncedInput
```

### `components/my-component.js`

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [text, setTextDebounced] = useDebouncedInput({ debounceTime: 200 })

  return (
    <Form>
      <Field
        type="text"
        name="textField"
        placeholder="Type something..."
        onChange={(e) => setTextDebounced(e.target.value)}
      />
      <div>output: {text}</div>
    </Form>
  )
}
```

### An Example Using Redux, Fetching, and Validation

Here's a partial example of using a custom hook for a debounced field validator.

Note: I did notice that Field validation seems to not validate `onChange` but you can expect it `onBlur` when you leave the field after your debounced update has executed (I did not try racing it or with a long debounce to see what happens). This is likely a bug that should be opened (I'm in the process of opening a ticket).

#### `hooks/use-debounced-validate-access-code.js`

```js
const useDebouncedValidateAccessCode = () => {
  const [accessCodeLookUpValidation, setAccessCodeLookUpValidation] = useState()
  const [debounceAccessCodeLookup, setDebounceAccessCodeLookup] = useState()
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const debouncedValidateAccessCode = (accessCodeKey, debounceTime = 500) => {
    if (debounceAccessCodeLookup) clearTimeout(debounceAccessCodeLookup)

    setDebounceAccessCodeLookup(
      setTimeout(
        () =>
          setAccessCodeLookUpValidation(
            dispatch(getAccessCode(accessCodeKey)) // fetch
              .then(() => undefined)               // async validation requires undefined for no errors
              .catch(() => 'Invalid Access Code'), // async validation expects a string for an error
          ),
        debounceTime,
      ),
    )

    return accessCodeLookUpValidation || Promise.resolve(undefined)
  }

  return debouncedValidateAccessCode
}
```

#### `some-component.js`

```js
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const debouncedValidateAccessCode = useDebouncedValidateAccessCode()

  return (
    <Field
      type="text"
      name="accessCode"
      validate={debouncedValidateAccessCode}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Opened this issue for async validation errors: https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/3409